# Определение задержки RTMP- и HLS-потоков

Tags: streaming, rtmp, hls

Пишем сервис стриминга, в очередной раз встал вопрос синхронизации видеопотока с посылаемыми клиенту событиями. Каким образом можно проанализировать задержку конкретного клиента относительно стримера? Сам стрим ведется в RTMP и HLS через несколько процессоров, включая CDN; есть пара идиотских наколеночных алгоритмов, но они ненадежны.